# Rally Lookback, Snapshot with empty custom field

Tags: rally, custom-fields, lookbackapi, lookback

I am trying to get a snapshot of deleted userstory to get value for a custom field(c_Dep). I get the snapshot but the custom field is empty. It had value in it. Does lookback not save value for cutomer created cutom field?

```
                findConfig: { 
                    _TypeHierarchy: 'HierarchicalRequirement',
                    "ObjectID": 12345,
                       "_ValidFrom": {
            "$lte": "2017-01-25T19:00:57.475Z"
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sarita, It is hard to tell from the information you have given what is going on precisely. However, I can give you some pointers
The Lookback API will store changes in values for custom fields. The selection you have shown is valid from 24thJan to 25thJan. During this period was the custom field set? Probably not, because the array is only one long and I think it is showing the creation event.

Was the custom field updated to contain something after this time period?
The reason for asking is that a common misunderstanding is that the records stored in the lookback database will hold the current value of fields - it doesn't. It holds the changes in fields. If c_Dependencies didn't change during that time period, you may not see an entry returned in the array. The next entry in the database might be the record where the c_Dependencies field was set (changed from null to something) and that might be 'after' your time period filter.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your query is requesting snapshots earlier than 2017/1/25 (`$lte`). Since there's only one, it's probably the creation snapshot. If you get all snapshots for the `ObjectID` by removing the `_ValidFrom` parameter, you should see the changes made to `c_Dep` after artifact creation.

Comment: I got rid of _ValidFrom and it gave me back all the snapshot but using rest node api, i am not able to fetch the c_Dep field. Could there be any reason why node rest api would be different?

Comment: In the response from your original post, the c_Dep field is being returned. In your snapshots, is the field not being returned? Or are the values still empty when they shouldn't be?

Comment: It returns the field when using Rally lookback.SnapshotStore (sort of like testing). I am now trying to return its value inside a script. I am using node rest api(request url for snapshot artifact) and my custom field is not being returned.It returns other fields like projects and Release.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the node rest api, or how it differs in making the request from SnapshotStore. You can try to add the field as a fetch parameter, explicitly telling the API to return it.

Answer (score 0):

As I am not allowed to comment, I have to post a new answer.

I think William Scott meant remove the ValidTo filter. The one you have is the creation change. The update will be afterwards.

Comment: The original query had a _ValidFrom parameter, no _ValidTo. The returned snapshot contains both of those fields.